# jQuery Accordion width - firefox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, firefox

The full width of container for my jquery accordion (100%) works in all browsers except for firefox. 
I have tried adding 'important' to prevent this, however firefox is the only browser so far the rejects the full width

please can someone assist me?

Thank you

```
/* Vertical Accordion Style */

.container {
        width:100% !important;
        position:relative;
        margin:40px auto 0 auto;
        top: -17px;
        left: 0px;
}


.va-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#000;
        left: 0px;
}
.va-slice{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.va-slice-1{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Airfreight10.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-2{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Seafreight2.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-3{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Satellite.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-4{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Guarding11.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-5{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Move3.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-6{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Investigations2.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-7{
    background:#000 url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/transport2.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.va-slice-color-1{
    background-color:#97c5eb;
}
.va-slice-color-2{
    background-color:#68ace5;
}
.va-slice-color-3{
    background-color:#0072cf;
}
.va-slice-color-4{
    background-color:#0039a6;
}
.va-slice-color-5{
    background-color:#00338e;
}
.va-slice-color-6{
    background-color:#002c76;
}
.va-slice-color-7{
    background-color:#002144;
}
.va-title{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:40px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px white;
}
.va-content{
    display:none;
    margin-left:25px;


}
.va-slice p{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family:Georgia, serif;
}
.va-slice ul{
    margin-top:20px;
}
.va-slice ul li{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 2px;
}
.va-slice ul li a{
    color:#000;
    background:#eede2f;
    padding:3px 6px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.va-slice ul li a:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:none;
}
.va-nav span{
    width:40px;
    height:25px;
    background:transparent url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/prev.png) no-repeat center center;
    position:absolute;
    top:-35px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-20px;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    opacity:0.7;
    cursor:pointer;

    z-index:100;
}
.va-nav span.va-nav-next{
    background-image:url(http://www.fsi.lookinside.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/next.png);
    top:auto;
    bottom:-35px;
}
.va-nav span:hover{
    opacity:1.0;
}


/* End Additional CSS Styles */
```

Answer (score 0):

I  found a solution - in case anyone else has this issue:

"position: absolute"

```
.va-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#000;
        left: 0px;
}
```